# Check if Array has all ID values from another Array of Objects ( ReactJS )

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I need some help.

I have two arrays and I must check if first array has all the ID values from another arrray of objects in React and then return just "True" or "False". First array looks like this:

```
this.state = { firstArray: ["1"] }
```

Second Array looks like this:

```
this.state = { secondArray: [ {id:1, name: Joe}, {id:2, name: Bill}, {id:3, name: Jason}]
```

I tried something like

```
compareTwoArrays = () => { 
    this.state.firstArray.includes(x => x === this.state.secondArray.map(item => item.id) 
)}
```

Any idea if how is this possible to make it return just "True" or "False" ?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You can use `.some()` or `.every()` with `.includes()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a combination of the `every` and the `includes` functions as follow:

```js
const firstArray = ["1"]
const secondArray = [ {id:1, name: Joe}, {id:2, name: Bill}, {id:3, name: Jason}]

const condition = firstArray.every(id => secondArray.includes(obj => obj.id === id))
```

This will test that every item in the first array has a corresponding object in the second array.

EDIT:
If what you need to do is the other way arround then the solution is

```js
const firstArray = ["1"]
const secondArray = [ {id:1, name: Joe}, {id:2, name: Bill}, {id:3, name: Jason}]

const condition = secondArray.every(obj => firstArray.includes(id => obj.id === id))
```